# Python: Run-Length Encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, sequence, run-length-encoding

I'm getting an error if the input only contains a character without a number attached to it. For example, if the user were to input "a2bc" the output should be "aabc". I have to meet the run-length format. The decode function works if its  "a2b1c1". The single character doesn't recognize any of it. I played with the conditions and debugger. I can't seem to meet the format for run-length.

The code displayed below were my attempts. I commented on the block where I tried to fix my problems.

```
def decode(user_input):

    if not user_input:
        return ""

    else:
        char = user_input[0]
        num = user_input[1]

        if num.isdigit():
            result = char * int(num)

        # elif num.isalpha():
        #     # this should skip to the next two characters

        else:
            result = char * int(num)

        return result + decode(user_input[2:])

test1 = decode("a2b3c1") 
test2 = decode("a2b3c")
print(test1)
print(test2)
```

(Note: the output for test2 should be `"aabbbc"`)

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This requires two changes: as you already figured out, if `num` is not actually a number, then you only use the char once and skip one character ahead. Otherwise you use the number and skip two characters ahead.
But you also need to handle a single character without a number at the end of your string. You can solve this by not only checking if `user_input` is empty, but whether it only has one character - in both cases you can simply return the string.

```py
def decode(user_input):
    if len(user_input) < 2:
        return user_input

    char = user_input[0]
    num = user_input[1]

    if num.isdigit():
        return char * int(num) + decode(user_input[2:])
    else:
        return char + decode(user_input[1:])
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes so much sense. Now if I were to put a 2 digit number like print(decode("a15") I noticed that it only recognizes the 1 and print out "a5" as the output. How do I deal with that?

Comment: Instead of only looking at the second char, you would have to repeatedly look at the next chars as long as they are numbers (`isdigit()`). Then you would read the number accordingly, and skip all of these characters instead of only the two.

Answer (score 1):

You should advance by 1 instead of 2 when the next character is not a digit (i.e. the 1 is implicit):

```
def decode(user_input):
    if len(user_input) < 2 : return user_input
    multiplier,skip = (int(user_input[1]),2) if user_input[1].isdigit() else (1,1)
    return user_input[0] * multiplier + decode(user_input[skip:])
```

*note that doing this recursively will constrain the size of the input string that you can process because of the maximum recursion limit.*